# Definir tipo de dado da coluna do DataTable como date

Tags: jquery, data, plugin, datatable

tenho um DataTable que exibe os valores vindos de um banco de dados SQL, desta forma:

```
<table id="tabelaLogs">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Código</th>
            <th>
                Data
            </th>
            <th>
                Tipo
            </th>
            <th>
                Descricao
            </th>
            <th>
                Criador
            </th>
            <th>
                Computador
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.codigoLog)</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dataHora)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tipo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.descricao)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.criadoPor)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.computador)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Como vocês podem ver a coluna número 1 (Começando a contar do 0), é uma coluna que exibe um valor vindo do BD que é uma Data, no formato que a data é vista no meu PC, no formato Americano, MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS A.

Porém, quando é passado para o DataTable, o tipom Date é passado como String. Caso eu execute este comando no console do Chrome: tabelaLogs.column(1).data[0], ela retorna isso: "17/8/2017 21:35" . Uma String.

Queria que retornasse uma variavel do tipo Date, como essa: Thu Aug 17 2017 21:35:00 GMT-0300 (E. South America Standard Time)

Para que eu possa filtrar a tabela registros que possuam a data, entre duas outras.

Eu já iniciei meu DataTAble com esse cóodigo, mas mesmo assim o tipo de dado da coluna continua como String.

```
tabelaLogs = $("#tabelaLogs").DataTable({
                "columnDefs": [
                    { "sType": "date", "targets": 1 }
                ]
            });
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?